# In pandas extract data for a particular date, having different timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset `d1_DataFrame` as:

```
dateTime                open    high           ...                          
2021-05-07 10:05:00.0  300.95  301.60  
2021-05-07 10:06:00.0  301.45  302.00  
2021-05-07 10:07:00.0  302.00  302.25  
2021-05-07 10:08:00.0  302.10  302.60  
2021-05-07 10:09:00.0  302.50  302.60 
...  ... ...
2021-06-03 15:53:00.0  325.65  325.65
2021-06-03 15:56:00.0  325.65  325.65  
2021-06-03 15:57:00.0  325.65  325.65  
2021-06-03 15:58:00.0  325.65  325.65  
2021-06-03 15:59:00.0  325.65  325.65
```

Containing open high prices from `2021-05-07 10:05:00` to `2021-06-03 15:59:00`

I want to extract/call data for a particular date like:

```
2021-05-07 10:05:00.0  300.95  301.60  
2021-05-07 10:06:00.0  301.45  302.00 
...        ...        ...
2021-05-07 15:38:00.0  300.95  301.60  
2021-05-07 15:39:00.0  301.45  302.00
```

or

```
2021-05-07 START-TIME OPEN CLOSE
.....
2021-05-07 END-TIME OPEN CLOSE
```

And loop over the dataset for each date available, while extracting data for a particular date.

I tried:

```py
date = pd.date_range(start = '2021-05-07 09', end = '2021-06-03 09');
for i in date:
    data = d1_DataFrame.loc[i];
    data.drop(data[data['volume'] == 0].index, inplace = True)
```

but got an error

```
    KeyError: Timestamp('2021-05-07 09:00:00', freq='D')
```

Comment: What is `volume` column and what are you trying to achieve. ¿Drop the rows between your defined dates, that have a `0` in `volume` column?

Comment: I have data for one month, I am trying to loop over data for a one day at a time.

Comment: See the edit of my solution to incorporate the solution into your loop

Comment: @ajsn looping is usually considered an antipattern in the pandas world. This is why i'm asking the final result that you expect.

Comment: @Francisco ok, i want to apply a function to calculate which would require the data for each day only. As, if whole data is provided then error/noise will be carried forward.

Comment: @SeaBean, yes it worked too.

Comment: @FranciscoPuga, yes i am also dropping the rows between your defined dates, that have a 0 in volume column. That part ok. Is there another solution to it?

Comment: @asjn my solution at the edit part already incorporated your complete logics, though your other parts of logics is not yet optimized.

Comment: @Seabean, it's working nicely. like what is not yet optimized. Looping is used for a one time calculation, if that's you are suggesting needs optimization.

Comment: I mean not optimized because of using a loop.  Anyway, if your dataset is not big and the run time is reasonable, you can keep on using it.

Comment: well, will look over it over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way of understand [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) method of pandas is as a generator, something like Python built-in `range`. You must select the start and end date, but also the frequency, like one day, or one minute or whatever.

Whith the expresion that you are using, you are generating the "days" between your start and end date:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.date_range(start = '2021-05-07 09', end = '2021-06-03 09')

DatetimeIndex(['2021-05-07 09:00:00', '2021-05-08 09:00:00',
               '2021-05-09 09:00:00', '2021-05-10 09:00:00',
               '2021-05-11 09:00:00', '2021-05-12 09:00:00',
               '2021-05-13 09:00:00', '2021-05-14 09:00:00',
               '2021-05-15 09:00:00', '2021-05-16 09:00:00',
               '2021-05-17 09:00:00', '2021-05-18 09:00:00',
               '2021-05-19 09:00:00', '2021-05-20 09:00:00',
               '2021-05-21 09:00:00', '2021-05-22 09:00:00',
               '2021-05-23 09:00:00', '2021-05-24 09:00:00',
               '2021-05-25 09:00:00', '2021-05-26 09:00:00',
               '2021-05-27 09:00:00', '2021-05-28 09:00:00',
               '2021-05-29 09:00:00', '2021-05-30 09:00:00',
               '2021-05-31 09:00:00', '2021-06-01 09:00:00',
               '2021-06-02 09:00:00', '2021-06-03 09:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

But to use to extract date from `d1_Dataframe` with `loc` you need to generate "dates" that exactly match the contents of the `datetime` column. As they don't match you get the `KeyError`, meaning that '2021-05-07 09:00:00' is not a key of `d1_Dataframe`.

A easy way to extract the data by date is filter the dataset as:

```py
d1_filtered = d1_Dataframe.loc[
    (d1_Dataframe['dateTime'] >= '2021-05-07 09')
    & (d1_Dataframe['dateTime'] < '2021-06-03 09')
]
```

And there is no need to loop over the dataframe to drop the rows that match some condition. You can just get the indexes and pass it to `drop`

```py
index_of_rows_to_remove = d1_Dataframe.loc[
    (d1_Dataframe['dateTime'] >= '2021-05-07 09')
    & (d1_Dataframe['dateTime'] < '2021-06-03 09')
    & (d1_Dataframe['volume'] == 0)
].index
d1_Dataframe.drop(index_of_rows_to_remove, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Great. I added more code avoiding the loop to drop the rows @ajsn

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`dt.normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) to get the dates without time and then use `.loc` to select the rows by filtering with a Timestamp with your selected date, as follows:

**If you want to get only one particular date:**

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['dateTime']).dt.normalize() == pd.Timestamp('2021-05-07')]
```

Result:

```
             dateTime    open    high
0 2021-05-07 10:05:00  300.95  301.60
1 2021-05-07 10:06:00  301.45  302.00
2 2021-05-07 10:07:00  302.00  302.25
3 2021-05-07 10:08:00  302.10  302.60
4 2021-05-07 10:09:00  302.50  302.60
5 2021-06-03 15:53:00  325.65  325.65
6 2021-06-03 15:56:00  325.65  325.65
7 2021-06-03 15:57:00  325.65  325.65
8 2021-06-03 15:58:00  325.65  325.65
9 2021-06-03 15:59:00  325.65  325.65
```

**If you want to get a range of dates, instead of for one particular date,** you can further use [`.between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with the start date and end date, as follows:

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['dateTime']).dt.normalize().between(pd.Timestamp('2021-05-07'), pd.Timestamp('2021-06-03'))]
```

### Edit

If you want to incorporate the logics into your loop:

```
date = pd.date_range(start = '2021-05-07', end = '2021-06-03');
for i in date:
    data = d1_DataFrame.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['dateTime']).dt.normalize() == i]
    data.drop(data[data['volume'] == 0].index, inplace = True)
```

Comment: @ajsn  If my solution help you on the total solution, please consider to pick it. Thanks!

Comment: @ajsn  So, finally which solution you use ?